# Tracking field deletion

Tags: entities

How to track user activity to find the user behind the field deletion.

As an admin, I want to track user activity so that I can find the user who deletes the field from particular content type.

I have tried with following modules but there is no option to track field.

1. Entity delete log.
2. track field changes.
3. Message and rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the [Blame](https://www.drupal.org/project/blame) module, it logs all of the form submitted data of any form submitted on your website, whether that be a node form, an admin settings form, etc.

Comment: Nice suggestion! Expect this won't log fields deleted via `drush` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

With the right setup all you need is a little DevOps juice to find out.

I mean, why in the first place would you let anybody delete fields on live? Field UI, Views UI and certain other modules should be disabled on live. Now you can delete fields from within Drupal only by triggering certain (update-)functions that would need to be committed into a Git repo. With Git you can blame pretty easily and find the person who committed the corresponding lines of code.

With DevOps juice I mean that you should better setup continuous integration or some other automated deployment routine connected to your Git repo to do the admin jobs on live triggered by a Git release or Git merge to run a predefined set of commands (or a script) instead of you or anybody else clicking through the UI or login to the server to do this kind of stuff (via `drush` or similar).